# Why doesn't #is_a? work with an instance of ActiveRecord::NamedScope::Scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

I'm using Rails 2.3.9.  To illustrate the issue, suppose we have a named scope on a model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :has_isbn, :conditions => 'isbn IS NOT NULL'
end
```

If you get the class of the named scope, `ActiveRecord::NamedScope::Scope` is returned:

```
Book.has_isbn.class
# => ActiveRecord::NamedScope::Scope
```

However, if you use `#is_a?` or `===` to figure out whether it is a scope, it returns `false`:

```
Book.has_isbn.is_a?(ActiveRecord::NamedScope::Scope)
# => false
ActiveRecord::NamedScope::Scope === Book.has_isbn
# => false
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?  Calling a named scope returns an instance of `ActiveRecord::NamedScope::Scope` (if you look at `lib/active_record/named_scope.rb` in the Rails code, you can see it calls `Scope.new` and returns it), so why doesn't `#is_a?` and `===` return `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/17f336e2f00f419a41eb7effb817bd7ad3e84f0d/activerecord/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb#L105-110) from the `Scope` class:

```
NON_DELEGATE_METHODS = %w(nil? send object_id class extend find size count sum average maximum minimum paginate first last empty? any? respond_to?).to_set
[].methods.each do |m|
  unless m =~ /^__/ || NON_DELEGATE_METHODS.include?(m.to_s)
    delegate m, :to => :proxy_found
  end
end
```

Every method in `[].methods`--that is, every method an array responds to--is defined on the `Scope` instance to pass through to [the proxy object](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/17f336e2f00f419a41eb7effb817bd7ad3e84f0d/activerecord/lib/active_record/named_scope.rb#L165-167), except for the methods defined in the `NON_DELEGATE_METHODS` array. These are untouched, and notice that `class` is listed in there.

So, when you call `scope.class`, you get `Scope` as the response. But when you call `scope.is_a?`, you're actually calling `scope.proxy_found.is_a?`, and the proxy object in this case is an `Array`.

```
>> scope.is_a?(Array)
=> true
```

Comment: Ah... I missed this when looking at the Scope code.  Thanks for the answer!